# Promised Land vs Promised Ground in the Torah (ארץ vs אדמה)

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael

The Torah refers to the Promised Land with two different words: ארץ and אדמה.:

> "וְאָכַלְתָּ וְשָׂבָעְתָּ וּבֵרַכְתָּ אֶת־ה"א עַל־**הָאָרֶץ** הַטֹּבָה אֲשֶׁר נָתַן־לָךְ׃" ([Deut 8,10](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.8.10?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en))
>
> "כַּבֵּד אֶת־אָבִיךָ וְאֶת־אִמֶּךָ לְמַעַן יַאֲרִכוּן יָמֶיךָ עַל **הָאֲדָמָה** אֲשֶׁר־ה"א נֹתֵן לָךְ׃" ([Ex 20,2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.20.12?vhe=Tanach_with_Nikkud&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

I mean referring to the Land of Israel as the "Promised land", not just ground or soil elsewhere, like in "אֲרוּרָה הָאֲדָמָה בַּעֲבוּרֶךָ".

What is the difference and when each one is used?

Comment: In English, we translate the former as land and the latter as ground.

Comment: I don't see any promises in the two verses you cite.